# JQuery Dependency Files not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I"m trying to create this demo:  http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message

I first decided to copy the source code and modify the file paths so that everything would match up accordingly.  I changed the source path to the following, everything else I kept the same:

```
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

And my folder looks like this:

[image]

So theoretically I linked them all together correctly. But it doesn't appear to be the case when I click on the html file to test it.  It's supposed to look like this:

[image]

But instead it looks like this:

[image]

And I have no idea why. I was hoping someone could help me replicate the demo that I found online.  I'm not having much luck.   http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message  If anyone can figure it out I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: any error in browser console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the sequence of the files as given below. Since `jquery-ui` is dependent on `jquery`. You need to load the jQuery library first.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything you are doing is correct except the order in which you are including the scripts.

Do this...

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

`jQuery` must included first, and its dependencies later.

Comment: Not as issue with `jquery-ui.css` file

Comment: Thats true. I just reordered it so that `jquery-ui.js` comes after `jquery.js`.